# Datastructure ambiguity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I can't figure this interview question.

You have an array of integers. You need to provide another Data structure that will have these functions:

```
int get(int index)
void set (int index, int value)
void setall(int value)
```

They all do what you guess they're suppose to do.
The limitation is that every function is in O(1).

How can you design it so that setAll will be O(1).

I thought about adding another field to each  integer, that will point to an integer that will be changed every time setAll is called. the problem comes when someone call *setAll* and then *set* then *get*.

Edit: I changed the names of the variables so it would be clearer. Also, since you asked, get is suppose to return array[i], set(index, value) suppose to put the value value in array[index].

After `setall(index, value)` you should `get (get(i) == get(j) == value)` for every i,j in the array.

Comment: What is `i` in `set` and `setall` ?

Comment: I assume that n = length of the array, where efficiency is O(n)?

Comment: why would there be a problem if someone callet setAll, then set, and then get? (in that order, appearantly)
Also, it feels like this is a homework-question, rather than one that belongs in the `interview questions`  section.

Comment: Is this interview question? what position were you applying for? It seems more difficult and advanced than other interview questions. Am I supposed to know about concurrency, timestamp, etc.? Since I don't know any of them!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep a DateTime field ( or simply a counter ) with each element in the array, a setAllValue variable and setAllDateTime variable. With each set, update the DateTime/counter of the element. With SetAll, update the value and DateTime of setAllDateTime.

In get, compare the DateTime of SetAll with DateTime of the element, whichever is newer, return that.

Comment: @Hammar's solution using a version number is probably better. The issue with timestamps is that you rely on not having two changes with the same timestamp. This definitely depend on the frequency of the changes AND the resolution of your timestamp. For example Windows is reknown for its low accuracy.

Comment: @Matthieu @Hammer I think that in general, you get to choose the answer that helped you most because you asked the question, and you are looking for something specific. In this case, Hammer did gave a very good solution, a complete answer, I agree. But all I needed was what Sanrag Sood said. Only the idea :) Again, this is not to say that Hammer's answer wasn't good :) It is great!

Answer (score 31):

How about storing a "version number" with each variable, i.e.

```
 int globalValue, globalVersion;
 int nextVersion;
 int[] localValue, localVersion;

 int get(int i) {
     if (localVersion[i] > globalVersion)
         return localValue[i];
     else
         return globalValue;
 }


 void set(int i, int value) {
     localValue[i] = value;
     localVersion[i] = nextVersion++;
 }

 void setAll(int value) {
     globalValue = value;
     globalVersion = nextVersion++;
 }
```

Comment: @Eyal: depending on the number of updates, don't forget to deal with the version looping (back to 0 for unsigned, and becoming negative for signed).

Comment: The problem says `set(i)` not `set(i,value)` :-)

Comment: you can combine both answers by using the timestamp of the epoch time down to nanosecond precision since no 2 commands will complete on the same nanosecond. this is basically just a simple [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)

Comment: @Moron: I'm assuming that was a typo.

Comment: @hammar: Why didn't you assume `setAll(i)` was `setAll(i,newvalue)` too (replace all values sames as location[i] by newvalue)? :-)

Comment: @Moron: When in doubt, make the simplest assumption that makes it fit :)

Comment: @hammar: No, when in doubt, ask OP to clarify! If OP does not respond, he does not deserve an answer, but deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Moron Its really not that a difference if it is set(index, value) or set(index). If you think about it, let say that, after set(index), get(index) == 0. In this situation it make no difference of how you think to solve the problem. I mean, the value here, has no meaning.

Comment: @Eyal: Sorry, there is a difference. You might think the interpretation is obvious, but there could be multiple interpretations. For instance, prior to your edit, my comments above give a different (and IMO more interesting) interpretation to the methods.

Comment: @ Moron I didn't quiet understand what you ment in setAll(i, newvalue) but I understand that maybe I needed to make the defitions clearer. Thanks :) !

Comment: You used an array? Could you please elaborate a little your approach?